# Maximum independence number of any $d$-regular graph on $v$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

What I seek is a formula $F(v,d)=M_v$, where $v$ is the number of vertices in a group and $d\leq v-1$ is the degree that they ALL have to be ($d$-[regular graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph)$^{\dagger}$), which finds the MAXIMUM number of vertices $M_v$ that can be selected in such a way that no two selected vertices share a common edge, *i.e.*, [the independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)).$^{\dagger\dagger}$

For example:

$F(3,2)$ would represent

[image]

and the maximum number of vertices that can be circled so that no two share an edge would be $1$, so $F(3,2)=1$. Consider now the representations of $F(4,2)$ and $F(4,3)$:

[image]
[image]

$F(4,2)=2$ and $F(4,3)=1$

Also, notice that for higher $v$, *e.g.* [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/54068/39732), there exists the possibility of multiple types of networks some of which may be disjoint from other vertices in the group. For example, $F(4,1)$ could be represented as

[image]

---

Notes:

I think we can agree that $F(v,v-1)=1$.

---

<sub>$\dagger$ Erick Wong's contribution.</sub>

<sub>$\dagger\dagger$ Erick Wong's contribution.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a fairly straightforward problem using what we know about graphic degree sequences, but it probably involves analyzing several cases.  It turns the exact formula you are looking for was already worked out 50 years ago in Moshe Rosenfeld's thesis.  You can find the relevant info (Theorem 1) on p.263 of

M. Rosenfeld, "[Independent Sets in Regular Graphs](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02759743)", *Israel J. Math.* (1964) Vol 2:4, pp.262–272.

Although no longer visible for free, the preview used to be wide enough to see the statement of the theorem, which yields

$$F(v,d) = \min\{\lfloor v/2\rfloor, v-d\},$$

except that of course the function is undefined when $v,d$ are both odd.  The theorem also gives the precise bounds for the minimum independence number.

Comment: Holy s&#t! It has a proof too?

Comment: I'm sure it does, although I don't have access to a copy of the original paper.  It probably isn't hard to reconstruct this part of the argument, the hard work is often in carefully identifying where the phase transitions are :).

Comment: Wait, $v=3$ is odd and $d=1$ is odd, but $F(3,1)$ should give $1$.

Comment: @uwnojpjm No, as I said $F(3,1)$ is undefined.  There is no graph on $3$ vertices with degree $1$ at every vertex.

Comment: Oh, wait, you're right, oops, I meant 3,2. Yeah, the Rosenfeld theorem clearly states no loops.

Comment: That theorem is a great relevant find. How did you find that so quick?

Comment: @uwnojpjm Oh, looks like the proof of the upper bound fits on the same page.  So the only thing left is to construct graphs which achieve the bound.  Also, it looks like the theorem is only intended for $d>0$ even though it says "integers".

Comment: Well, I just searched for "maximum independence number of a regular graph".  It wasn't the first match but it was on the first page.  Also I have worked closely with Prof. Rosenfeld in the past so my attention was immediately drawn to that link :).