# Is there a graph G that has neither a Hamilton path nor a Hamiltion cycle?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

If we want a connected graph, can we make it so it has neither a Hamilton path or Hamilton cycle? Is there a way to prove that there isn't a connected graph with these properties?

Comment: Sure, there are many such graphs. Any tree that is not a path for example. (The star is a quick example.)

Comment: [There are even $3$-regular examples.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2755458/is-there-a-finite-connected-3-regular-graph-with-no-hamiltonian-path)